# Check if user input is float or integer

Tags: c

I have created the following program to see if input from user is a float or an integer. The problem is sometimes it says the input is float and sometimes ts says it is integer. Even a number like `1.24` is integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

        float num1;

        printf("Enter number: ");
        scanf("%lf", &num1);

        int num2 = num1;

        if (((num2 * 100) % 100) == 0) {

                printf("float \n");
        }
        else {
                printf("integer \n");
        }
}
```

Comment: this will not work for numbers below 1.0

Comment: It would be much more reliable to simply search the string for a decimal point. This method is prone to all kinds of errors.

Comment: if (ceil(num1) == num1) then integer

Comment: @AndréPuel It is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Actually it is likely not to work at all as it is float equality operator which is bad always.

Comment: `int num2 = num1; if (((num2 * 100) % 100) == 0)`... How can this condition ever be false?? I have to put my glasses.

Comment: `float num1; ... scanf("%lf", &num1);` is bad.  Mis-matched type and format specifier.

Comment: @EugeneSh. My motivation is that for user input numbers it will be fine. Of course, if the number is the result of an expression then it will probably fail. Like ceil(2.28*100) == 2.28*100

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are assigning num1 to num2, and num2 is declared as integer.

```
Means if you do like:
num1=34.5;
then after num2=num1;
num2=34; not 34.5
```

Hence,your number become integer here.

And % doesn't work for float as we know.

If you want to check your input as float or integer, then you can ceil function

```
if(ceil(num1)==num1)
```

This'll surely work.

I'm pasting here sample for that :

```
    float num1;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num1);

    if (ceil(num1)==num1) {

            printf("integer \n");
    }
    else {
            printf("float \n");
    }
```

Comment: Where does the OP use the modulo operator on a `float`?

Comment: @pallavi thank you for the answer. It is still the same.

Comment: @Mrs.Husain, It still gives 1.24 as integer

Comment: @pallavi yes it still gives it as an integer!

Comment: @Mrs.Husain, giving float on my machine

Comment: @pallavi 1.24 is given float, but a number like 2,2222 is given integer. Still thank you for your help and time. =)

Comment: @Mrs.Husain, but 2,2222 is an integer, then it must give it as integer.

Comment: @pallavi how is 2.222 an integer? Forgive me if I am wrong, but isn't any number that has a fractional part a float?

Comment: Be clear about `.` and `,` as decimal point and thousand's separator.  Different place have different conventions.

Comment: @Mrs.Husain, what is ' %lf ' in 
                     scanf("%lf", &num1);